# $M_t=B_{tX}$ is a local martingale?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, martingales

Let $X$ a positive random variable independent of a Brownian motion $B_t$. Let $M_t=B_{tX}$ and $\mathcal{F_t}=\sigma\{X,B_{s}, s\leq tX\}$. We want to show that M is a $\mathcal{F}_t$-local martingale.

I tried to take the sequence of stopping time $T_n=\inf\{t>0:|B_{t(X+1)}|>n\}$ but I have the problem that X is not independent of $\mathcal{F}_t$.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: This looks like a time-changed Brownian motion, though the notation is a bit strange. What filtration do U assume for $B$?

Comment: For B I assume the standard generated filtration

Comment: $\mathcal{F}_t=\sigma\{B_s, s\leq t\}$

Comment: The definition of the filtration $\mathcal{F}_t$ (in your question) doesn't make sense (more precisely the part "$s \leq tX$"... note that the right-hand side is a random variable whereas the right-hand side is a (deterministic) constant).